# search xml using xpath based on various element values

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

```
<OverallReport>
    <Results>
       <Data1>
            <a> -30 </a>
            <b> 400 </b>
       </Data1>
       <Data2>
            <MoreData>
                    <c> 2 </c>
                    <d> 100 </d>
           </MoreData>
           <MoreData>
                    <c> 4 </c>
                    <d>200</d>
           </MoreData>
       </Data2>
   </Results>
   <Results>
       <Data1>
            <a> -50 </a>
            <b> 600 </b>
       </Data1>
       <Data2>
            <MoreData>
                    <c> 2 </c>
                    <d> 200 </d>
           </MoreData>
           <MoreData>
                    <c> 6 </c>
                    <d>500</d>
           </MoreData>
      <Data2>
   </Results>
</OverallReport>
```

I have an XML document, such as the above, that contains any number of Results nodes and any number of MoreData nodes. I must find the results node that contains two specific values (e.g. a=-50, b=600), and within that node, find the value of ‘d’ if ‘c’ is equal to a specific value.

So essentially, if a=-50, b=600, c=6, what is the value of d (it’s sibling).

I am trying to do this using XPath. So far, here is what I have:

```
var resultsNodes = document.SelectNodes(“OverallReport/Results”);
var data1ANodes = document.SelectNodes(“OverallReport/Results/Data1/a”);
var data1BNodes = document.SelectNodes(“OverallReport/Results/Data1/b”);

var data2CNodes = document.SelectNodes(“OverallReport/Results/Data2/c”);
var data2DNodes = document.SelectNodes(“OverallReport/Results/Data2/d”);

string wantedA = “-50”;
string wantedB = “600”;
string wantedC = “6”;
string wantedD = "500";

for (int i=0; i<resultsNodes.Count; i++)
{
    if (data1Anodes[i].InnerXml == wantedA && data1Bnodes[i].InnerXml == wantedB)
    {
       //do something.
       //the goal is to compare the output of D with wantedD
        i = resultsNodes.Count;
    }
}
```

Everything that I have tried does not give me what I need, as the XPath for all D’s are the same. I am new to XML so maybe there is something I’m overlooking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string wantedA = "-50";
string wantedB = "600";
string wantedC = "6";

string xpath = string.Format("OverallReport/Results[Data1/a={0} and Data1/b={1}]/Data2/MoreData[c={2}]/d",
    wantedA, wantedB, wantedC);

XmlNode nodeD = document.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
Console.WriteLine(nodeD.InnerText);
```

Comment: I love you so much, Alexander! This was a lot simpler than I thought. Thank you!!!!!

Comment: Btw,  I have posted a new question as there is an additional layer to this (there will be multiple matching a, b,c's and I must find the x'th one).